# Spotlight does not index mail

Tags: mail.app, spotlight

Spotlight does not deliver any result from mail messages (although searching inside Mail.app works)

I tried to re-index the mails with the following result:

```
$ mdimport -Vp -d 4 -r /System/Library/Spotlight/Mail.mdimporter
Total processing time spent in importer plug-ins: 0.000000 seconds for 0 files
Top 0 most expensive files for importer plug-ins:
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: are you trying to search inside emails for a specific text.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Anything: text, from, to. No problems inside the application but nothing is found with spotlight.

Comment: The From & To & Subject should work in Spotlight.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD It should work, as it works on all my other machines ...

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a re-index of the whole drive. Check out this help page at Apple: [Re-index folder or drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716)

Also looking in there might show that the mail folder has been hidden for privacy.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure the Mail & Messages is not **un**checked in the Spotlight preferences pane.

There are 3-rd party utilities that will delete your spotlight index (I use Onyx) forcing the Mac to rebuild it from scratch. I would try that after verifying the above item is checked off.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-indexing your system drive.

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

This will delete and re-create your Spotlight index.